# Could not execute statement SQL Grammar Exception

Tags: java, hibernate, entities

Here is my entity class.

```
@Entity
public class Store implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Store() {
    }

    @Id
    private int id;
    private String code;
    private String password;
    private String forgetPasswordNote;
    private String key;
    private String ownerId;
    private String storeLink;
    private String activationCode;
    private String name;
    private String homepageUrl;
    private String sessionToken;
    private Date dateCreated;
    private Date expireDate;
    private Date lastModified;
    private String nmPassword;
    private String storeType;
    private String premium;
    private double money;
    private boolean refreshed;
    private String country;
    private String lang;
    private String varId;
    private String fbPageId;
    private boolean fbEnabled;
    private boolean informative;
    private boolean active;
    private String fbEnabledBy;
    private String ipAddress;
    private String comments;
    private float commission;
    private String picasaEmail;
    // all getter and setter goes here

}
```

Here is my controller

```
@Controller
public class RegController {
    @RequestMapping(value =  "/create/database")
    public String createDatabase(ModelMap map, HttpServletRequest request) {
        Store store = new Store();
        store.setId(1);
        store.setCode("1");
        System.out.println("test worl");
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure()
                .buildSessionFactory();
        try {
            Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
            session.beginTransaction();
            session.save(store);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
            session.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
        return "home";
    }
}
```

When I run the url localhost:8080/MyApp/create/database I am getting and error. org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
Is there any reserved keyword on my entites class?

Comment: I have defined the entities class on my controller. And also defined the entities class on hibernate.cfg.xml file too.

Comment: I have found the solution key is reserved keyword on mysql database so I simply change the key to storekey and everything work fine.

Comment: money is not keyword. The keyword is "key".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution key is reserved keyword on mysql database so I simply change the key to storekey and everything work fine.